# Regex Pattern for exclude control characters and include all language charactes tab and new line must include

Tags: java, regex, control-characters

We have set of inputs like *'java-> Way->
Project  test'*.
ex:
[image]

We need to eliminate control characters only.
we used [\p{C}] for matching those characters unfortunately it matches the the tab space and new line characters. Kindly give(Valid regex pattern) solutions to solve this issue.

Comment: we used [\p{C}|\t|\r\n]* not working

Comment: we also tried [^P\{Cc}\t\r\n] also but not working

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can use this regex:

```
[\p{Cntrl}&&[^\p{Space}]]
```

This will match a **control character** i.e. `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]` except a **whitespace character** i.e. `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`

[Java RegEx Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

In Java use:

```
String re = "[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\\p{Space}]]";
```

**Example:**

```
String title = "xyz a\u0000b\u0007c\u008fd\u0009 - foo \u0009 bar";
title = title.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\\p{Space}]]", "");
System.out.printf("[%s]%n", title);
//=> [xyz abcd   - foo   bar]
```

Comment: Hi we tried but removes tab space and new line characters too. any suggestions

Comment: What is your sample input string?

Comment: java to Way to
Project  test , contains control character , tab space and new line ;  ex take it in question image

Comment: I posted a sample code and it is NOT removing tab or any space.

Comment: we have some different scenarios so code not to be alter only regex pattern need' finding valid (utf-8)code points , the Matcher.match should return true if(no control characters) false if(control characters only)

Comment: When you use `.matches` it must match complete string. For ex: `"\u0007\u0008".matches("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\\p{Space}]]+")` will return `true`